# Missing warning dialog for deinstallation while application is running on mac

Tags: install4j

I am missing the dialog that appears when I trying to uninstall the application while this one is still running an mac os. At windows os there appears a dialog with the message to shutdown the application before retry deinstallation. Isn't this functionality implemented for mac os? I am using version 5.1.13 of install4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1.x, this functionality is not implemented for Mac OS X.

Comment: Ok. It should be possible to implement a script manually to check this. But is it possible to call the dialog by the script which is displayed on windows os so that the appearance would be the same?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We're currently working on install4j 6 and it might get implemented for that version.